# R histogram scale_x_binned() gets an empty last bin - and 'right' option appears to be working in reverse?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am using geom_bar() and scale_x_binned() to make a histogram with the ticks between the bars.
But the right-hand bin shows as empty.

I tried the option [in the docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_binned.html) that allows you to choose whether a value on the border between bins goes in the left or right bins. Changing it meant the last bar appeared. But it appears to be working with inverse logic from expected, which is also odd.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

Time = c(17, 14, 21, 19, 18, 24, 25, 14, 17, 19, 20, 17, 21, 20, 23, 27, 25, 25, 27, 29, 24, 22, 26, 29)

# Note there are the following counts:
# 14: 2, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 3, 18: 1, 19: 2 ... 
#
# The 16-18 bin should either get 3 or 4 depending on where the '18' lands.

data = data.frame(Time)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Time))+
geom_bar()+
scale_x_binned(right = TRUE, show.limits = TRUE)
```

But with right = TRUE (as above) the 16-18 bin gets a count of 4. That seems wrong - the 18 should have fallen in the 18-20 bin?

[image]

Now if I use right = FALSE, it appears to work they way I want (binning to the right) BUT now the last bar is missing (should have count of 2, for the two '29's):

[image]

What is going on here? This is R 3.6.2 on Windows 10, with R package versions:

```
other attached packages:
[1] Hmisc_4.7-2     Formula_1.2-4   survival_3.1-8  lattice_0.20-38 ggplot2_3.3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not solve your issues (I think we're finding problems with the `ggplot2` code here), but to look at the two problems in reverse order:

First, it seems that `show.limits` is putting scale limits in place which is cutting off the last bar somehow. Removing it works:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Time = c(17, 14, 21, 19, 18, 24, 25, 14, 17, 19, 20, 17, 21, 20, 23, 27, 25, 25, 27, 29, 24, 22, 26, 29)

data = data.frame(Time)


ggplot(data, aes(x = Time))+
  geom_bar()+
  scale_x_binned(right = FALSE)
```

[image]

(but oddly putting a new `xlim` in place doesn't reverse the problem)

Secondly, the `right` option is doing the opposite of what it says in the help file, but is entirely consistent with `base::cut`:

> right: logical, indicating if the intervals should be closed on the right (and open on the left) or vice versa.

When using `cut(..., right = TRUE)` the values are the same as `scale_x_binned(..., right = TRUE)` ("closed on the right" = right values of bins include values on the threshold; i.e. values on threshold are binned to the *left*).

```r
mutate(data,
       bins = cut(
         Time,
         breaks = seq(14, 30, by = 2),
         right = TRUE,
         include.lowest = TRUE
       )) |>
  count(bins)
#>      bins n
#> 1 [14,16] 2
#> 2 (16,18] 4
#> 3 (18,20] 4
#> 4 (20,22] 3
#> 5 (22,24] 3
#> 6 (24,26] 4
#> 7 (26,28] 2
#> 8 (28,30] 2
```

It may be that:

- The wording on `ggplot2` helpfiles needs changed
- The issue of cutting x scale needs highlighted?

These seem consistent with my version of R too:

```r
#>  version  R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

#>  ggplot2     * 3.4.0       2022-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
```

### Edit - small update

If you want to `show.limits = TRUE` you can specify upper limits in the `scale_x_binned` function. I *think* it is naturally putting in an upper limit of 29, and so then when putting in a 28-30 bin it then automatically cuts this off.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = Time))+
  geom_bar()+
  scale_x_binned(right = FALSE, show.limits = TRUE, limits = c(14, 30))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming this (and for opening the GitLab issue) I've also opened one for scale.limits. Problem with specifying limits to scale_x_binned is that without having run the binning function, I don't know what the bins are!

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5094

Comment: Hi Dan - sorry for stealing your issue-thunder for the `right` argument documentation! Had gotten really curious and went ahead and opened a new issue. Very rude of me. Hope other issue goes well too!

Comment: No worries  - let's see what happens. Then we can post an answer!

Comment: the documentation has since been fixed https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/5137